# Is it possible to do diffrent Selects in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with:

```
id  integer
name text
sumbuy numeric
priority integer
....
```

table contains:

```
id , name , sumbuy, priority, ...
1    xx     33       12 
2    dd     45        7
4    aa     54        0
```

I need to write a query that gives informatio based on `priority` column.
The thing is that the data is changed based on priority.

```
Select case when priority>0         then 'High'::Text
            when popartid<=0        then 'Low'::Text

    end as Emg,*
from A
```

this yeilds:

```
Emg, id , name , sumbuy, priority, ...
High  1    xx     33       12 
High  2    dd     45        7
Low   4    aa     54        0
```

But my goal is when the `Emg` is `Low` to have diffrent data which I give in manually.   =>   `name` will be 'not important' `sumbuy` will be 0.
So what I want to see is:

```
Emg, id , name,            sumbuy, priority, ...
High  1    xx              33       12 
High  2    dd              45        7
Low   4    not important   0        0
```

basicly, What I am asking is if it's poosible for a select statment to perform diffrent instruction based on data in the row...
something like:

```
Select case when priority>0 
                then 'High'::Text as Emg, id, name, sumbuy, priority                                                      
            when popartid<=0
                then 'Low'::citext as Emg, id, 'not important' as name, 0 as sumbuy, priority
from A
```

this isn't `case` syntax but it demonstrat what I want.

How do I do that other than writing two diffrent queries?

Comment: Do a UNION ALL instead, or with several case's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by 2 ways I think of

1.

```
Select case when priority>0 
    then 'High'::Text 
    else 'Low'::citext end as Emg,
    id,
case when priority>0 then name else 'not important' end as name,
case when priority>0 then sumbuy else 0 end as sumbuy
..
..
from A
```

2.

```
select 'High' as Emg,id,name,sumbuy,priority from A where priority>0
union all
select 'Low' as Emg,id,'not important' as name,0 as sumbuy,priority from A
where priority <=0
```